# Richtext type attribute in Datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I have a column which displays rich text in a lightning data table, how do I escape the special characters?Is there any type attribute?

Answer (score 8):

LightningDatatable doesn't support rich text type, that's why you see all your text AS IS.
If you want to display formatted rich text you should extend standard LightningDatatable with your new custom column type.

```
import LightningDatatable from "lightning/datatable";
import richTextColumnType from "./richTextColumnType.html";

/**
 * Custom component that extends LightningDatatable
 * and adds a new column type
 */
export default class MyCustomDatatable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        // custom type definition
        richText: {
            template: richTextColumnType,
            standardCellLayout: true
        }
    }
}
```

I've created **(clicable link) [gist](https://gist.github.com/loktevich/044d9411985c03a314765dbe05328eb3)** for this simple issue as it's not very clear from the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation).

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I've added some details. BTW, all links for gist and docs were already clickable before my edit.